# Loop through worksheets in workbooks in a folder

Tags: excel, vba, loops, directory, spreadsheet

This is a good one.
I can loop through workbooks and change/format on the sheet that the workbook was last saved on, but I cannot change/format/loop through the remaining sheets in the workbooks that possess multiple Sheets, my code wont work.

NOTE: The macro runs from a separate .xlsm.

Here is my current code (3 sub's):

```
Sub DarFormatoExelsEnFolder()
'Revisar todos los archivos xlsx en una carpeta y aplicar formato 
definido

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimizar Macro
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Definir carpeta destino
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'Si es cancelado
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Definir extensiones a dar formato
  myExtension = "*.xlsx*"

'Definir ruta y extensión
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Revisar todos los archivos en la carpeta
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Variable de libro abierto
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Confirmación de libro abierto
      DoEvents

    'Cambios al Workbook

WorkSheetChange

     'Guardar y cerrar Workbook actual
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Confirmación de libro cerrado
      DoEvents

    'Proximo libro
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Aviso de fin de ejecución
  MsgBox "Operación Completada"

ResetSettings:
  'Normalizar excel
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub WorkSheetChange()
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Format

Next WS

End Sub

Sub Format()

    'Format certain cells

End Sub
```

Shout out to give credit to the people from "The Spread Sheet Guru", that have gotten me this far...

Answer (score 0):

If you use thisworkbook, this will only loop the sheets in the Macro File(Excel Fiel where Code Written). So You need to pass the workbook **WorkSheetChange00 wb** and loop that workbook (**WorkSheetChange00(wb as Workbook)**).

```
Sub WorkSheetChange00(wb as Workbook)
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  For Each WS In wb.Worksheets
     WS.activate
     Format
  Next WS
End Sub

Sub DarFormatoExelsEnFolder()
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim myPath As String
 Dim myFile As String
 Dim myExtension As String
 Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

 'Optimizar Macro
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Definir carpeta destino
 Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

 With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
 End With

 NextCode:
 myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

myExtension = "*.xlsx*"
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Do While myFile <> ""
'Variable de libro abierto
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
'Confirmación de libro abierto
  DoEvents

'Cambios al Workbook

WorkSheetChange00 wb

 'Guardar y cerrar Workbook actual
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Confirmación de libro cerrado
  DoEvents

'Proximo libro
  myFile = Dir
 Loop

 'Aviso de fin de ejecución
 MsgBox "Operación Completada"

ResetSettings:
'Normalizar excel
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you DevK... Unfortunately it still doesn't switch/loop through the sheets. It definitely goes to every workbook in the folder and formats the sheet that was last active before closing/saving the individual workbooks.

Comment: Added a new line WS.activate. Please try with this code and let me know

Answer (score 0):

***Eureka!!!***
1. This VBA will ask for a folder
2. Loop Through all the files that end in ".xlsx"
   2.0 In each sheet of every workbook
   2.1 Format first line as table headers
   2.2 Inserts 5 rows (shifts down)
   2.3 Adds an image from range and 3 labels (from macro origin workbook)
   2.4 and a 4th label that marks the name of the sheet and last modified date/time.

And last but not least, it prompts "Task Completed" (in Spanish)..lol...

*And if you run again it will skip the files/sheets that all ready have the "Company Name" (aka:range.("C1") ) in C1 per sheet...*

***Feel free to mod to your liking..***

In 2 subs...

Here is the working code (paste in standard module):

```
Sub DarFormatoExelsEnFolder()
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim myPath As String
 Dim myFile As String
 Dim myExtension As String
 Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimizar Macro
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Definir carpeta destino
 Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

 With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
 End With

NextCode:
 myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

myExtension = "*.xlsx*"
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Do While myFile <> ""
'Variable de libro abierto
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
'Confirmación de libro abierto
  DoEvents

'Cambios al Workbook

Format wb

'Guardar y cerrar Workbook actual
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Confirmación de libro cerrado
  DoEvents

'Proximo libro
  myFile = Dir
 Loop

'Aviso de fin de ejecución
 MsgBox "Operación Completada"

ResetSettings:
'Normalizar excel
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
'_______________________________________________________

Sub Format(wb As Workbook)
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws_num As Integer

Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning
ws_num = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To ws_num
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate

If Range("C1") <> "Company Name" Then

 'Sheet format start

  Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rows("1:5").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    'Pega o Llena información y logo predeterminados
    Workbooks("REPORTE.xlsm").Worksheets("BACKEND").Range("F3:F3").Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
        Workbooks("REPORTE.xlsm").Worksheets("BACKEND").Range("F4:F4").Copy Destination:=Range("C2")
            Workbooks("REPORTE.xlsm").Worksheets("BACKEND").Range("F5:F5").Copy Destination:=Range("C3")
                Workbooks("REPORTE.xlsm").Worksheets("BACKEND").Range("LogoBR").Copy Destination:=Range("A1")
    Range("C4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveSheet.Name & " - Actualizado el: " & ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
    Range("C1:C4").Select
    Range("C4").Activate
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

End If
    'Sheet format end

Range("A1").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
'Numera las hojas
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(1, 1) = 1
Next
'reactiva hoja inicial
starting_ws.Activate

End Sub
```